# Django-Heroku Deployment Procfile

Tags: django, heroku

I've created a basic Django app and I wanted to deploy it with Heroku. I have followed all the instructions given on Heroku but there was one error I made which was naming the file "procfile" instead of "Procfile". Now the website has been deployed but it only opens up to an application error. Upon checking the log, I have found the error code to be H14. I have since renamed the "procfile" to "Procfile" but the change doesnt seem to be integrated. How do I fix this?

Comment: commit your code to git and push to heroku -> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code

Comment: @iklinac I committed and deployed on Heroku through the GitHub repository option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the change on your repository, commit it, and push the applicable branch to Heroku. Finally, try to run Heroku again.

Comment: Alright thanks, the change wasn't committed properly because I didn't add the change to the Heroku git repository. I fixed it by renaming it on GitHub and then deploying it on Heroku through GitHub.